# How to call function only if certain element is loaded and in markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an external API which builds up a div structure (on page load it adds `.build-div`) in my markup. I want to modify this structure with JS/jQuery. Question: How can I call a function as soon as the markup is there to manipulate. My attempt:

```
function changeStructure() { $('.build-div').appendTo('.another'); };
window.onload = changeStructure;
```

but it seems that this doesn't work. What works is:

```
function changeStructure() { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
     $('.build-div').appendTo('.another'); }, 500) 
};
window.onload = changeStructure;
```

but I don't want to hardcode any guessed timeouts in order to make the function work. So how can I detect if an element is there and fire the function as soon as it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: As you have asked for `how can I detect if an element is there `..If an element exists.. then `$('.build-div')` wont be returning null...

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar so what would be a good way to write this function? Checking via interval as long as `$('.build-div');` is not returning null anymore?

Comment: If you are just waiting for the page to finish loading, you could use `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR STUFF})`

Comment: Do you request another api data with js? If it is - shouldn't there be some callback where you can palce all your needed code?

Comment: What kind of API you are using? How you download created markup by that API?

Comment: @u_mulder yes it gets requested with js, and no there isn't a callback.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar - jquery selector function never returns `null`. You have to check `$("...").length to find out if any elements that match the selector exit.

Comment: This can't be true( Can you show how your request to api works?

Comment: Unless "external API" provides means of signalling that it has completed DOM modifications, you will have to resort to using `setInterval`/`clearInterval` or chained `setTimeout`s.

Comment: @Igor thanks, thats what I was basically asking for. Could you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless "external API" provides means of signalling that it has completed DOM modifications, you will have to resort to using setInterval/clearInterval or chained setTimeouts.

```
function changeStructure() { 
  if ($('.build-div').length > 0)
  {
    ... your code
    $('.build-div').appendTo('.another');
  }
  else
    setTimeout(changeStructure, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If the API has no event/callback, you could use the `DOMNodeInserted` event.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.build-div')) {
        $(e.target).appendTo('.another');
    }
});
```

Note: this has no support in IE8. Other than this, you will have to use a timer to keep checking if the element has been added, until it has and then you can append it elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, indeed a good way, but I will need IE 8 support so I guess I will go for the interval.

Answer (score 2):

[Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might be worth looking into. They allow you to react to changes in the DOM. I wrote a [jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/bjedrocha/jquery.observe) using Mutation Observers as an experiment. The plugin is by no means production ready but perhaps it can serve as a basis for your work.

Note that Mutation Observers are only supported by modern browsers. If you're looking for a more universal solution, you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) to periodically check for the existence of `$('.build-div')` and then clear the interval once it's loaded.